# Superset LDAP User - Admin Role with all permissions and still Access is Denied

Tags: ldap, apache-superset

I'm currently setup a Superset system with LDAP authentication. My personal account from LDAP should get all permissions, so I have granted the predefined admin role to it.

But when I try to access "Settings" -> "List Users" I get "Access is Denied".

If I reconfigure Superset to use local Accounts, the cli created admin-account can access this page and this account also uses the same admin role.

Do I miss something here?

My Superset version is 0.38.0

Comment: Same issue here, but using Google SSO rather than LDAP. I'm still searching for solution. Someone mentioned run `superset init` command would fix this, but I got no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you should run `superset init`, it works in our environment.